# Compute the Redwolf Checksum™ of some data

Tags: code-golf, base-conversion, checksum

*I will preface this by saying that I made this for fun; I have absolutely no formal knowledge on cryptography or error correction. Do not use this algorithm in anything remotely important.*

I was kind of bored a few days ago, so I decided to write a simple function to take some data and return an easily memorable (but not necessarily secure :p) checksum of it. The output format is a number of digits in base 36, between `0` and `z` (think of it like hexadecimal, but with all the letters used).

Your program or function will take two inputs: `data`, and `block_size`. The `data` will be a list of values `0` to `255`, and the `block_size` will be at least `4`. It will return a base 36 string (or list of values 0-36) with the length `block_size`.

Using `[182, 109, 211, 144, 65, 109, 105, 135, 151, 233]` and `4` as the inputs, this is how you would find the checksum:

1. The length of the `data` is padded with zeroes to a multiple of the `block_size`

   ```
   182, 109, 211, 144, 65, 109, 105, 135, 151, 233, 0, 0
   ```
2. The `data` is broken into blocks based on the `block_size`

   ```
   182  109  211  144
    65  109  105  135
   151  233    0    0
   ```
3. For each item `n` of the resulting block, take the sum of all items at position `n` in one of the above blocks mod 256

   ```
     182  109  211  144
   +  65  109  105  135
   + 151  233    0    0
   --------------------
     142  195   60   23
   ```
4. Take the binary representation of each item in the result

   ```
   10001110
   11000011
   00111100
   00010111
   ```
5. For each item, add the least significant five bits of the next (wrapping) item, and the least significant bit of the (wrapping) item after that (note that this value can be higher than `256`)

   ```
      10001110   11000011   00111100   00010111
   +     00011      11100      10111      01110
   +         0          1          0          1
   --------------------------------------------
      10010001   11100000   01010011   00100110
   ```
6. Convert back to decimal, and take the mod 36

   ```
   1, 8, 11, 2
   ```
7. Covert into base 36

   ```
   18b2
   ```

A reference implementation can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/RedwolfPrograms/cf650c0b22274a019ae91e92eb6b7380). Input and output can be in any reasonable manner.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest in bytes per language wins!

### Test cases

```
[]; 8                           -> 00000000
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]; 8     -> 14589cd8
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]; 6     -> eb589b
[0, 4, 2, 1]; 48                -> 473100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[195, 180, 1, 0]; 4             -> 0123
[31, 32, 65, 4]; 4              -> wxyz
[20, 8, 247, 41]; 4             -> tw4p
[250, 175, 225, 200]; 4         -> ewhb
[33]; 3                         -> (does not need to be handled)
```

Comment: Can the base36 letters be uppercase?

Comment: @xash Yes, the case doesn't matter at all

Comment: So in terms of binary operations that CPUs actually do, this is a SIMD sum of byte elements (with normal binary wrapping), similar to x86 `paddb` / `_mm_add_epi8`, reducing to 4 elements if you used a wider vector in the main loop.  Then take that 4-byte "word" SIMD-byte-add two rotated and masked copies of it.  (`x + rotl(x, 8)&0x1f1f1f1f + rotl(x, 16)&0x01010101` where + is a SIMD byte add).  It's very likely not a good checksum, but can run very fast on modern CPUs, just as fast as a simple sum of 4-byte integer elements.  (Or faster for large unaligned buffers; group at the end.)

Comment: (One difference from how you described it is that you don't need to "convert" numbers to binary; integers in normal computers are already in binary.  But it's not a bad thing to describe it that way, just overly complex for people used to languages with binary numbers.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I noticed that when I was writing it, but figured it would make more sense to explain it that way and that most people would know to optimize that out.

Comment: Oh I just realized that block_size=4 was only an example; it's not as easy as I thought to use CPU SIMD like MMX for the general case.  In case anyone's interested, https://godbolt.org/z/rasY5P is a 3/4-finished x86 MMX implementation of that case, with main loop without odd-size handling, and the rotate/mask/add parts.  Probably not viable as an answer because it doesn't easily extend to a variable block_size.

Answer (score 6):

### Thumb-2 (ARMv6T2, no div instructions), <s>118</s> <s>116</s> <s>112</s> 110 bytes (ascii base 36)/102 bytes (values)

I believe there is still some optimization room for sure.

Raw machine code, 16-bit hex little endian

Base 36 ASCII version:

```
b5f0 ebad 0d03 466f 001d 2600 3d01 557e
d1fc b151 5dbc f810 5b01 192d 55bd 1c76
429e bf08 2600 3901 d1f4 003c 1e9d 7866
78a1 f000 f80c 3d01 d1f9 7866 7839 f000
f806 783e 7879 f000 f802 449d bdf0 f814
0b01 f006 061f 0849 4170 3824 dafd f110
01fb bfc8 3027 3054 f802 0b01 4770
```

Without ASCII conversion ('values')

```
b5f0 ebad 0d03 466f 001d 2600 3d01 557e
d1fc b151 5dbc f810 5b01 192d 55bd 1c76
429e bf08 2600 3901 d1f4 003c 1e9d 7866
78a1 f000 f80c 3d01 d1f9 7866 7839 f000
f806 783e 7879 f000 f802 449d bdf0 f814
0b01 f006 061f 0849 4170 3824 dafd 3024
f802 0b01 4770
```

Uncommented assembly:

```armasm
        .syntax unified
        .arch armv6t2
        .thumb
        .globl redwolf
        .thumb_func
redwolf:
        push    {r4-r7,lr}
        sub.w   sp, sp, r3
        mov     r7, sp
        movs    r5, r3
        movs    r6, #0
.Lmemset_loop:
        subs    r5, #1
        strb    r6, [r7, r5]
        bne     .Lmemset_loop
.Lmemset_loop_end:
        cbz     r1, .Lsum_loop_end
.Lsum_loop:
        ldrb    r4, [r7, r6]
        ldrb.w  r5, [r0], #1
        adds    r5, r4
        strb    r5, [r7, r6]
        adds    r6, #1
        cmp     r6, r3
        it      eq
        moveq   r6, #0
        subs    r1, #1
        bne     .Lsum_loop
.Lsum_loop_end:
        movs    r4, r7
        subs    r5, r3, #2
.Lchecksum_loop:
        ldrb    r6, [r4, #1]
        ldrb    r1, [r4, #2]
        bl      checksum
        subs    r5, #1
        bhi     .Lchecksum_loop
.Lchecksum_loop_end:
        ldrb    r6, [r4, #1]
        ldrb    r1, [r7]
        bl      checksum
        ldrb    r6, [r7]
        ldrb    r1, [r7, #1]
        bl      checksum
        add     sp, r3
        pop     {r4-r7, pc}

        .thumb_func
checksum:
        ldrb.w  r0, [r4], #1
        and.w   r6, r6, #31
        lsrs    r1, r1, #1
        adcs    r0, r6
.Lmodulo_loop:
        subs    r0, #36
        bge     .Lmodulo_loop
.Lmodulo_loop_end:
#ifdef ASCII
        cmp.w   r0, #9 - 36
        it      gt
        addgt   r0, #'a'-10-'0'
        adds    r0, #'0'+36
#else
        adds    r0, #36
#endif
        strb.w  r0, [r2], #1
        bx      lr
```

[Try it online! (sorta)](https://travis-ci.com/github/easyaspi314/easyaspi-ppcg/jobs/471971267#L500)

#### Explanation

C signature:

```c
void redwolf(const uint8_t *data, size_t data_size, char *block, size_t block_size);
```

First, we push our registers and set up a VLA. (`uint8_t chars[block_size]`)

```armasm
        push    {r4-r7,lr}
        sub.w   sp, sp, r3
```

Since we like narrow instructions, and there is no narrow `ldrb Rd, [Sp, Rn]` instruction, we use a frame pointer to cut down code size.

```armasm
        mov     r7, sp
```

Zero out the VLA we created.

```armasm
        movs    r5, r3
        movs    r6, #0
.Lmemset_loop:
        subs    r5, #1
        strb    r6, [r7, r5]
        bne     .Lmemset_loop
```

If we have data, sum everything up.

```armasm
.Lmemset_loop_end:
        cbz     r1, .Lsum_loop_end
.Lsum_loop:
        ldrb    r4, [r7, r6]
        ldrb.w  r5, [r0], #1
        adds    r5, r4
        strb    r5, [r7, r6]
```

`r6 = (r6 + 1) % block_len` without division

```armasm
        adds    r6, #1
        cmp     r6, r3
        it      eq
        moveq   r6, #0
```

Decrement data_len and loop if non-zero.

```armasm
        subs    r1, #1
        bne     .Lsum_loop
```

Now, we checksum the data and convert to base 36.

We do a simple loop for all but the last two bytes in `chars`, calling a subroutine (with a custom calling convention) to handle the arithmetic.

We pass the second two bytes as parameters, while `checksum()` will do `*r4++` to load the first byte and increment.

```armasm
.Lsum_loop_end:
        movs    r4, r7
        subs    r5, r3, #2
.Lchecksum_loop:
        ldrb    r6, [r4, #1]
        ldrb    r1, [r4, #2]
        bl      checksum
        subs    r5, #1
        bne     .Lchecksum_loop
```

Process the wrapped data. I feel this could be optimized better.

```
.Lchecksum_loop_end:
        ldrb    r6, [r4, #1]
        ldrb    r1, [r7]
        bl      checksum
        ldrb    r6, [r7]
        ldrb    r1, [r7, #1]
        bl      checksum
```

Restore the stack, pop registers, and return.

```armasm
        add     sp, r3
        pop     {r4-r7, pc}
```

checksum subroutine

We call `checksum` with `r6 = chars[i + 1]` and `r1 = chars[i + 2]`, with `r2` still pointing to `block`.

Load `chars[i]` from `r4` and increment the pointer. This is a step outlined from the other three calls.

```armasm
        ldrb.w  r0, [r4], #1
```

Now we need to do `chars[i] + (chars[i + 1] & 31) + (chars[i + 2] & 1)`.

First, we mask the lowest five bits of `chars[i + 1]`.

```armasm
        and.w   r6, r6, #31
```

Now, we use `lsrs` to get the lowest bit of `chars[i + 2]` in the carry flag...

```armasm
        lsrs    r1, r1, #1
```

...so we can add them both with an add-with-carry. Done.

```armasm
        adcs    r0, r6
```

Modulo by 36 using a naïve subtraction loop. No `udiv` required. Not that I would use it anyways - `movs` + `udiv` + `mls` would be 10 bytes, this is 4.

Note that this will end up negative, we need to add 36 after to get the correct result.

```armasm
.Lmodulo_loop:
        subs    r0, #36
        bge     .Lmodulo_loop
```

Convert to base 36 (ascii version):

If r0 + 36 is > 9, we add the additional offset to get it from `r0 + '0'` to `r0 + 'a' - 10`.

```armasm
.Lmodulo_loop_end:
        cmp.w   r0, #9 - 36
        it      gt
        addgt   r0, #'a'-10-'0'
        adds    r0, #'0' + 36
```

Adjust offset (non-ascii)

If we are outputting integers, just add 36.

```armasm
        adds    r0, #36
```

Store the char into block and increment the pointer.

```armasm
        strb.w  r0, [r2], #1
```

Return back to the main function.

```armasm
        bx      lr
```

Answer (score 5):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>84</s> <s>67</s> 63 bytes

-17 bytes by reshuffling things, inspired by @Neil's comment, -4 bytes from more golfing

```
{(`c$&2!&49\5673099)36!+/256 32 2!'y':(y+2)#+/(0N;y)#x,&y-y!#x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#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)

- `+/(0N;y)#x,&y-y!#x` take the column-wise sum of the input split into `y`-length chunks (filling with 0s)
- `y':(y+2)#` build a list containing the original input, it rotated once, and it rotated twice
- `256 32 2!'` mod the original input by 256, the rotated-once input by 32, and the rotated-twice input by 2
- `36!+/` sum column-wise, modding by 36
- `` (`c$&2!&49\5673099) `` build list of base-36 characters (digits followed by lower case letters), which is indexed into by the results of the above

Comment: Having to specify the list of rotation amounts seems awkward, but not knowing K I don't know whether you're better off always rotating and then undoing one rotation later.

Comment: @Neil thanks! Managed to find a way to remove that redundancy, which also (somehow) removed the need for another round of 0-padding!

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 59 bytes

```
(Num_j_,Alpha_j_){~]($!.0)36|[:+/256 32 2|i.@3|."{+/@([\~-)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ldDLasJAFAbgfZ7irxSSITrOPZNAQVvoqrjoViUYL8TQ0m6KVYOvnk6MXcTLwgMHZvHNzzmnqDrUX@EpgY8uGBLXPYqX97fXKhj9fKZF2h1@fOcz9yD7wzR4fKCMSFOOk7AvtIEUEOWaDmRJO/uwPwjGk0OPVMRbzvMvBL5PsILFlRo9U7BTNZqBQ0BCQcMgan2sNVfaxvOFvaVNSy8zp7N/q5zlzih7bQ4VSc7uqCaVxxrc1nOwOvlyOy5kIyWvD2W0Q@fwKDe/210jhXZ5kYYQrlk797jVJs88r/oD)

- `([\~-)` data x split in blocks of size y, padded with zeros
- `+/@` sum each column
- `i.@3|."{` rotate row by 0, 1 and 2, so we get 3 rows
- `256 32 2|` mod rows by 256, 32 and 2
- `[:+/` sum again
- `36|` mod 36
- `]($!.0)` lengthen list to size of y, padded with zeros
- `(Num_j_,Alpha_j_){~` take the indices from `0…Z`

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>24</s> 18 bytes

```
ιO₁%DÀ31&DÀÉ++₆%₆B
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3E7/R02Nqi6HG4wN1YDk4U5t7UdNbapA7PTf678JV7ShpamOgqGFAZDQUTCIBQA) or [Try all cases!](https://tio.run/##lY/NSsNAEMfv@xRDaFywmyabbJOUQA8iXn2A1EM@VhOUJHQj8RO0B8FH8ty7D9EXiZOYKtIqODCzzMyP/382jlTWtjLJSjAKoO9vp5vVs368fnL4Adb163i8Wb3omEcU5pCUqZxEsSSkyfIrCUsZpZAX1XUdQFoSgK2SNuqnGixw@ABKpkCVCaZ5QYdWmcbkEPuBiJpLME5oQIHeV8u8qM9B09Wi0JXGYGRj8kc6sGZZ1WapojiXw/N9WFoWsm3DswB8@D2MOVhDkNBiwBmghcNAMJgycBl4XwrIcjH1Z0nq/8G6W1bGyMY9KXqS41b4ey4QnsOtfwQJ@QwNuf95hNXp7vyK2w4JHVw7aO0iLnawjmtubu9IaKOSj0cKDzm@T69uRIXctLP0UM22u2L99O5@3WQx@QA)

**Commented**:

```python
ι                    # create block_size lists of every block_size-th element
                     #   [data[0::block_size], data[1::block_size], ..., data[block_size-1::block_size]]
 O                   # sum each list
  ₁%                 # modulo 256
    DÀ               # duplicate the resulting list and rotate the copy left
      31&            # bitwise and 31 / take the 5 least significant bits
         DÀ          # duplicate this list and rotate left again
           É         # is the value odd? / least significant bit
            ++       # sum the three lists element-wise
              ₆%     # modulo 36
                ₆B   # convert to base 36
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>122 121</s>  114 bytes

Expects `(data)(block_size)`. Returns an array of characters.

```javascript
a=>w=>a.map((v,i)=>b[i%w]+=v,b=new Uint8Array(w))&&[...b].map((v,j)=>((v+b[++j%w]%32+b[-~j%w]%2)%36).toString(36))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY9BbsIwEEX3nGI2gK0YEzsmCQtH6hmqriIWDgSaiCYoWLh00aunY0hbUCtVncV4LL///7g2J3Ncd9XBzpp2U/Zb3RudOZ0Z/mIOhJxYRXVW5NXYrQJ9YoVuSgdPVWPTh64zZ@IonUxyznmx@lTUqMAzKPIgqFE3jiTOs/fLLOk4iim37aPtqmZH8EJ7Wx4taDCgM3C@rdvm2O5Lvm93ZEsMxRhet1VDplNKRyPPk3xFSUrh95rPIRxqoEMGgoFkEDFQDBYMYgbJ1QNpoRbpcr1J/6LjC10WSBffrLqwAt/V/UrIqiQS4T9qcBVLDBXpdZHQO9O73wkZDWSEQITxMQrUPehJ93p@G0iJbimuqhIkxQ9P69Thi/TBCTpK6Vt4s4FPd8@2/wA)

### Commented

#### Step 1 to step 3

```javascript
a.map((v, i) =>         // for each value v at position i in a[]:
  b[i % w] += v,        //   add v to b[i mod w]
                        //   there's an implicit modulo 256 because ...
  b = new Uint8Array(w) //   ... b[] is initialized to an array of w unsigned bytes
)                       // end of map()
```

#### Step 4 to step 7

```javascript
[...b]                  // we need to split b[] so that the results returned by the
                        // callback function of map() are not forced to unsigned bytes
.map((v, j) =>          // for each value v at position j in b[]:
  (                     //
    ( v +               //   compute the sum of v
      b[++j % w] % 32 + //   and b[(j + 1) mod w] mod 32
      b[-~j % w] % 2    //   and b[(j + 2) mod w] mod 2
    ) % 36              //   modulo 36
  ).toString(36)        //   converted to base-36
)                       // end of map()
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 122 bytes

```r
function(d,b,m=matrix)c(0:9,letters)[1+colSums(m(rowSums(m(c(d,!1:(b-sum(d|1)%%b)),b))%%256,b+1,b)[1:3,]%%2^c(8,5,1))%%36]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7LasMwEEX3/Qp1YZDIDWj0sGWTfkWXIYXasYshssEPmkX/3R3hFi9G3DnDmdG0deJyFlu3Ds3Sj4O8o0Z8i5/L1D9VI3VV4tEuSzvN6kqnZny8r3GWUU7j919q2HmlStbneY3y/kMqy2qlwJVlxueoT8TNlSqLG5OPRgZ4UBrb/LZ1sh@W9qudpFYI6qXjo8UR8hT4I3AwLMGFHVDJO4IGgTW3M0uwBrnn/h8ZjQDjCjg6mGet8DCGSx86BQNBuoQwRJycg@BlOyKdkk2P56GxNnnbLw)

Output as a list of base 36 digits (lowercase).

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 87 bytes

```
Y($+_)%256M(@>g<>@g)ZD0
((,tALz)Jx)@_M($+_)%36M Z[{@RVTBa}My{FB((TBa)@>-5)}M(@>y)AL@yy]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/UkNFO15T1cjUzFfDwS7dxs4hXTPKxYBLQ0OnxNGnStOrQtMh3heiyNjMVyEqutohKCzEKbHWt7LazUlDA8jUdLDTNdWsBRlQqeno41BZGfv/vwmXoYURl6GBJZeRoSGXoYkJl5kpmGtoAKSNgdjUkMvI2Pi/bhEA)

This was much harder than I expected.

Input is taken as a list of lines. First line is `block_size`, rest of the lines are the data.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-a`, 96 bytes

```perl
$#r=<>-1;map$r[$i++%@r]+=$_,@F;say map{((0..9,a..z)x9)[$_%256+$r[++$j%@r]%32+$r[($j+1)%@r]%2]}@r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYu9DoIwFIX3PkUTLwmkpWkrBUytYXLzCQwhHRwgqKQ6@BNf3XphdznJOef7plMYTYywCm67y5U9@wnCEXrGkia0zEHHm729@SfF552mUogN90K8sscmO0KXaFMyNBiDYTaStZ5rCgNT2TLo9tOEaJvg0sxC72Bw0kbJacGp5lSRoibaYFeVwUXPISUpiMatxlJUyCJGZmZx1ouMYMlpRep/R/m9Tvf@ernF/GCEVDLmfvwB)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>161</s> 159 bytes

```python
lambda d,b:(d:=d+[0]*(b-len(d)%b),r:=range(b),s:=[sum(d[i::b])%256for i in r],[[str(k:=(s[i]+(s[(i+1)%b]&31)+(s[(i+2)%b]&1))%36),chr(k+87)][k>9]for i in r])[2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZLZbsMgEEXf/RUjVamgJpJZvATJ@RHKQyhObSXGlu0qTX/eBTfqorSROg8jQGculxn681R3jhf9MO/Lx/m4a43dgSVGIitLG6tEPyCzPlYOWbwymAyyHHbuuUJ@PcpSjS8tsqqR0mi8Ymm27wZooHEwaKLUOA3oIEs0qkbHPqMmpl5G33OKL3u27CnGK55h8lT7grjIsVaH7UZ/U8OK6bktVYSUJgWGv@NuvYXkEhFBKiFACTACnIAgkBLICOSfIgGnIi02T7a4hWdfeGU8bi6wWGCqibh2FWCRc5r8I4Is3fhrafFhJfHS@PqFlPGAck9wbyDzFeKKXNDT6/ktoMzrFd6tyD1Kf1WdTqJf0DTcnXtNxkJKfppYmnCqlxZwrgnHN6eBbFeN4LoJXFVZmDowFdQ7Z4@VxZGOojBnF@bcyigU@Q8IJbhl3Q@Nm9Ae@TOM53c)

Edit:

- changed `range` to variable to reduce 2 characters

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 106 bytes

```ruby
->a,n,c=[0]*n{a.size.times{|i|c[i%n]+=a[i]&255};(1..n).map{|i|((c[i-1]+c[i%n]%32+c[-~i%n]%2)%36).to_s 36}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lc/baoNAEAbg@z7FELBosy57VEOwLyJLUWvIXsRKNJiTfXU7RtsU24t2LpaF/f6Znf0hO/WbuPefU1KSPE6YeSovKa3tuaCN3RX15WqveWKd0izjNLHmUWjdrV1OaenRXVoN766LwudmOUJHCrz577e78BwZeLR5e6lBBl3XV4emhk2SGAKRgTiGBZtqQfNtuq8fPgUjwAkIApKAIqAJBATCe44rHa3y1@jPuWDMFRnmsl9S6pbiKNU0QoWSs3/UvClf4XQejT9iQ@NpZS7k3EokEucHemBftD2eznMq9NAxRCjEcLBvrYt2@2M3gTxCp0Jk/G6bVlWT7T8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 29 bytes

```
⭆η⍘﹪ΣＥ851﹪↨Φθ¬﹪⁻⁻ξμιη¹Ｘ²Ｉλ³⁶φ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYvBDoIwEER/ZcOpTdbEUiAYb5p4w5BwJBwaRGlSqEJR/75uFQ/zdjIz2/Zqaq0y3peTHh2rHJ1boe6sRzioufsFrLCXxVhWLQMLZZSnIkJY07BjJ21cN7EHwtm6/77Q4zKvfCMMHEGTes6JglTaFz3FCEc1O2Y4/zYyI1zJ7r2va5FTL7Y7hFgIckmCkKVrJLbByYCUyljKBiFp/OZpPg) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 η                              Block size
⭆                               Map over implicit range and join
      851                       Literal string `851`
     Ｅ                          Map over characters
            θ                   Data array
           Φ                   Filtered where 
                 ξ              Data index
                ⁻               Minus
                  μ             Character index
               ⁻                Minus
                   ι            Outer index
              ﹪                 Modulo
                    η           Block size
             ¬                  Leaves no remainder
          ↨          ¹          Convert from base 1
         ﹪                      Modulo
                       ²        Literal `2`
                      Ｘ         Raised to power
                         λ      Current character
                        Ｉ       Cast to integer
    Σ                           Take the sum
   ﹪                            Modulo
                          ³⁶    Literal 36
  ⍘                         φ   Convert to 0-z
                                Implicitly print
```

At one point conversion from base 1 is used to take the sum in case the list is empty (in which case the conversion is zero but the sum is None).

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 55 bytes

```
KeQJm%sd256.TchQKsm@+."/9ª!"G%++@Jd%@Jhd32%@Jhhd2 36K
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/3zs10CtXtTjFyNRMLyQ5I9C7ONdBW09J3/LQKn5pRSV3VW1tB68UVQevjBRjIxCVkWKkYGzm/f9/tKGFkY6CoYGljoKRoSGQZWKio2BmChUyNACxjEGEKVDSyNg4VkfBBAA)